# how to discard fractional part of a number in Node/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to discard the fractional part of a number in Node, but I can't get the correct result!!

```
parseInt(2.3*100) == 229
```

It's easy to do this in C:

```
(int) (2.3f * 100) == 230
(int) (2.305f * 100) == 230
```

How can I do this in Node?

pay attention: someFunction(2.305 * 100) should be equal to 230 too!

Some test in node:

```
$ node
> 2.3*100 == 230
false
> parseInt(2.3*100)
229
> (2.3*100)|0
229
> (2.3*100).toFixed(0)
'230'
> (2.305*100).toFixed(0)
'231'
> Math.round(2.3*100)
230
> Math.round(2.305*100)
231
> Math.floor(2.3*100)
229
```

Comment: you should use some bigdecimal for javascript ( https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js ) https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal

Comment: Math.floor() should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome to the unsettling world of floating point arithmetic. Contrary to what you state, all results are correct, just not what you expect. Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no nice workaround for this. Most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions. Read more here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Install decimal fron npm: `npm install decimal` and use as follows:

```
var Decimal = require('decimal');
parseInt(Decimal('2.3').mul('100').toNumber());
```

Comment: why C can do this? does it use different binary representation?

Comment: @Jake C uses IEEE 754 arithmetic; there are multiple standars; no sure what nodejs uses; you can also find some c examples that don't work as you expect